# CouchDB 3 Clouseau-based Full Text Search Bookmark for Previous Page

Tags: pagination, full-text-search, couchdb

The built-in **Clouseau**-based search in **CouchDB 3** would return a bookmark for paging to the next page of results. However, there does not seem to be a way to generate a link to page backward. I have tried to use the same bookmark and reverse the sort parameter, but it does not produce the desired result.

Is there a way to generate a previous link from the result of a **Clouseau** search?